# List of Mimetic Scenes

Tags: film, art

After many failed attempts to view it before, I finally sat down and watched Hitchcock's *Rear Window*

During the build up to Jimmy Stewart being confronted by the murderer, the scene struck me as almost completely the same as the scene in which Josh Brolin's character is confronted by Javier Bardem's Anton Chigurh at the hotel room in *No Country for Old Men*, a scene which has already been discussed here numerous times.

What other films have such homage in them (intended or not), and without it being a spoof! (Just to eliminate all the *[Insert adjective here] Movie* series and most of Leslie Nielsen's back catalogue!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Odessa Steps sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battleship_Potemkin#The_Odessa_Steps_sequence) in Battleship Potemkin is a famous one. It's been revisited in The Untouchables, The Godfather, Brazil, Star Wars Episode III and others...

Comment: Great example; it's amazing the influence one film can have on the art form.

Comment: Don't forget Naked Gun 33 1/3! :D

Answer (score 0):

*The Hunger Games* has a shot (a bunch of miners in a lift) that looks like it's lifted straight from *Metropolis*.